# Fuzzy search deep array only on certain properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JSON dataset which could be very large when it returns, with the following structure for each object:

```
{
    "ctr": 57,
    "averageECPC": 23,
    "cost": 2732.54,
    "margin": 66,
    "profit": 2495.9,
    "property": {
        "value": "Izzby",
        "uri": "/Terrago/2"
    },
    "status": {
        "content": "<p>Some Content</p>",
        "stage": 1
    },
    "alerts": {
        "status": 2
    },
    "revenue": {
        "value": 2573.13,
        "compare": 0
    },
    "children": [{
        "ctr": 79,
        "averageECPC": 54,
        "cost": 3554.78,
        "margin": 88,
        "profit": 3145.81,
        "property": {
            "value": "Comvex",
            "uri": "/Octocore/4"
        },
        "status": {
            "content": "<p>Some Content</p>",
            "stage": 1
        },
        "alerts": {
            "status": 2
        },
        "revenue": {
            "value": 1247.92,
            "compare": 0
        }
    }]
}
```

Now I want to search all objects in the array and return only objects which include a string of some sort, but I only want to search certain properties.

I basically have another array which contains the keys I want to search, e.g.

`const iteratees = ['ctr', 'property.value', 'status.stage']`

I have lodash available within the project, but I have no idea where to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: `which include a string of some sort` could you clarify this?

Comment: This is just the string I want to search for. For example I may want to search for the string 'izz', which should return the objects that have property.value set to "Izzby"

Comment: So some keys in iteratees should have some value that you want to search for and you want to return those objects.

Comment: Exactly yes. But only search keys which are within the iteratees array, no others.

Comment: Is it ok to flatten structure to one level first? with parentId to ref to each item's parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()`, `some()` and `reduce()` to do this.

```
const iteratees = ['ctr', 'property.value', 'status.stage'];
var searchFor = 'lo';

var result = arr.filter(function(o) {
  return iteratees.some(function(e) {
    var res = e.split('.').reduce(function(a, b) {
      if(a) return a[b];
    }, o);
    if(res) {
      if((res).toString().indexOf(searchFor) != -1) return true;
    }
  })
})
```

```js
var arr = [{
  "ctr": 'lorem',
  "averageECPC": 23,
  "cost": 2732.54,
  "margin": 66,
  "profit": 2495.9,
  "property": {
    "value": "Izzby",
    "uri": "/Terrago/2"
  },
  "status": {
    "content": "<p>Some Content</p>",
    "stage": 1
  },
  "alerts": {
    "status": 2
  },
  "revenue": {
    "value": 2573.13,
    "compare": 0
  },
  "children": [{
    "ctr": 79,
    "averageECPC": 54,
    "cost": 3554.78,
    "margin": 88,
    "profit": 3145.81,
    "property": {
      "value": "Comvex",
      "uri": "/Octocore/4"
    },
    "status": {
      "content": "<p>Some Content</p>",
      "stage": 1
    },
    "alerts": {
      "status": 2
    },
    "revenue": {
      "value": 1247.92,
      "compare": 0
    }
  }]
}, {
  name: 'lorem',
  ctr: 12,
  property: {
    value: 1
  },
  status: {
    stage: 1
  }
}, {
  name: 'ipsum'
}]

const iteratees = ['ctr', 'property.value', 'status.stage'];
var searchFor = 'lo';

var result = arr.filter(function(o) {
  return iteratees.some(function(e) {
    var res = e.split('.').reduce(function(a, b) {
      if (a) return a[b];
    }, o);
    if (res) {
      if ((res).toString().indexOf(searchFor) != -1) return true;
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, the searchFor string comes from user input via a text input, and the above seems awfully slow over an array of even just 100 objects. The above would be called onChange of the input